# Hibernate generating wrong SQL from HQL

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to join 2 tables, user and hosting_platform, using following HQL query. hosting_platform table has a FK reference to user table. 
Database is postgresql.

```
select u.id, u.userName, p.platform.id, p.itemPrice, p.revenueShare 
from User u left join HostingPlatform p on u.id = p.platform.id AND
p.item.id = :itemId where u.userType = 'Platform'
```

I am not getting expected results from above query because hibernate is not generating proper SQL query from above HQL. 
Following plain SQL is generated by Hibernate.

```
select
        user0_.id as col_0_0_,
        user0_.user_name as col_1_0_,
        hostingpla1_.id as col_2_0_,
        hostingpla1_.item_price as col_3_0_,
        hostingpla1_.revenue_share as col_4_0_ 
    from
        users user0_ 
    left outer join
        user_role user0_1_ 
            on user0_.id=user0_1_.user_id 
    left outer join
        hosting_platform hostingpla1_ 
            on (
                user0_.id=hostingpla1_.id 
                and hostingpla1_.item_id=?
            ) 
    where
        user0_.user_type='Platform'
```

Based on my HQL join should happen on user0_.id=hostingpla1_.platform_id but Hibernate is doing it on user0_.id=hostingpla1_.id.

HostingPlatform.java definition is as

```
@Entity  
@Table(name="hosting_platform")
public class HostingPlatform {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6311364761937265306L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "hosting_platform_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "hosting_platform_id_seq", sequenceName = "hosting_platform_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "platform_id")
    private User platform;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="item_id")
    private Item item;

    @Column(name = "item_price")
    private Double itemPrice;

    @Column(name = "revenue_share")
    private Double revenueShare;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing @ManyToOne annotation on 'platform' field in HostingPlatform.java.
Problem resolved after adding annotation

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "platform_id")
private User platform;
```